# How to style angular material?

Tags: angular, types, angular-material

I want to use `ngx-mat-intl-tel-input`,  but I cannot set any style. [image]. The button is taking 100% heigh everything `gx-mat-intl-tel-input` take 100% heigh. 
here is my code:

```css
.main {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.phone {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 300px;
}

ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>div>button {
    margin: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}

form {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

::ng-deep.mat-menu-panel {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 70vh);
}

.mat-button.mat-blue {
    color: blue;
}

.tp-button-row button,
.tp-button-row a {
    margin-right: 68px;
}

::ng-deep.mat-menu-panel {
    max-width: none !important;
}

::ng-deep ngx-mat-tel-input-container {
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<form #f=ngForm [formGroup]="phoneForm">
    <div>
        <ngx-mat-intl-tel-input style="border: 2px solid red; padding: 10px; margin-left: 100px;width: 100px; height: 100px;" [preferredCountries]="[ 'us', 'gb']" [enablePlaceholder]="true" name="phone" formControlName="phone" #phone></ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>
    </div>
</form>
```

// app.component file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  phoneForm = new FormGroup({
    phone: new FormControl('', Validators.required)

  });


  get f() {
    return this.phoneForm.errors;
  }






  ngOnInit() {
    // initialization logic goes here

  }

}
```

Comment: I think potential problem you might be facing is, your styles are not applied on the component. Maybe you used to try setting `encapsulation` as `ViewEncapsulation.None`

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik can you please explain a bit more ?

Answer (score 1):

Angular use css encapsulation, that's why your styles are not applied.

**if gx-mat-intl-tel-input is a component available in the project**, you need to put your css into this component (in gx-mat-intl-tel-input.component.css) and that's it.

**if you have no access to this component** (you took it from a library for example), first of all you need to check with a browser web tool developer how the component is build. Check the html and the css already applied in the component.

After that, you need to play with the css already existing with applying new rules or override pre-existant rule (!important is your friend)

You have 3 places to write your css :

- in the css file component using ngx-mat-intl-tel-input, apply your css rules with /deep/, >>> or ::ng-deep in front of each rule. It's disabling css encapsulation for a specific rule. Problem : **this method is deprecated.**
- disable the encapsulation in the entire component by using ViewEncapsulation.None :

```html
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
class AppComponent {}
```

Be carefull : if you do that, **all the css rules in app.component.css will be applied in all the project.** That's why i don't recommand you to do that because that's confusing : later, you will apply a rule in this component and forgot the ViewEncapsulation is set to None.

- Put your css in style.css, available in the root of your project. This will do the same than above, those rules will be applied in all your project but that's sound more logical because you know it is a global file. You can also use comments to clarify the desired scope of your css rules and avoid mess in your style.css

Answer (score 0):

Styling components don't work that way in Angular, as you have added.

```
 <ngx-mat-intl-tel-input style="border: 2px solid red; padding: 10px; margin-left: 100px;width: 100px; height: 100px;" [preferredCountries]="[ 'us', 'gb']" [enablePlaceholder]="true" name="phone" formControlName="phone" #phone></ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>
```

If you want to style the element, target first internal `div` or `whatever parent element` inside your `ngx-mat-intl-tel-input`, try to apply the styles to those `class`es.

If it still doesn't work, you can try setting `encapsulation` as `ViewEncapsulation.None`. But it has other side effects.
You can read more about it [here](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-viewencapsulation-in-angular).